# Flag emoji output

Tags: html, css

Is there a option to output a flag?

Like I can do

```
Hello
```

with an winking hand emoji.

I copy the flag emoji, but I get

insted of

[image]

Does anyone know how I can do it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your system probably does not support that emojii yet. Because it shows the flag for me, and it looks exactly loke the one shown in your picture.

Comment: @t.niese thanks for the comment. Is there a way to display this emoji regardless of the system?

Comment: An emojii is just a letter like `a` that is rendered differently so the system has to support it. You can embed a font in your website that supports emojiis, but regular font are only black and white and won't work well for flags due to that. OpenType-SVG  supports colors but is not widely supported yet. So currently the only way is - like you already did here - to use images (or svg) for the emojii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example of how you can integrate this into your website

The keyword to show the emoticon is: `[bgflag]`

*I used the flag from your post to make this emoticon - emoticon size is 16x16px*

Because @Niet the Dark Absol wrote in a comment that replacing information throughout the page is not a good idea. I made a change to the code. The replacement will only work in the DIV element `id="comments"`

```js
var emoji = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />';

var wrap = document.getElementById('comments');
if (wrap) {
    wrap.innerHTML = wrap.innerHTML.replace(/\[bgflag\]/g, emoji);
}
```

```html
<div id="comments">
    Lorem ipsum dolor [bgflag] sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, fuga totam! Ipsum nihil possimus quidem
    voluptates illo porro consequuntur libero quisquam dolor aliquid! Neque commodi [bgflag] ipsa vel beatae,
    incidunt
    minus?
</div>
```